# Get the last login date for Active Directory from a list of organizational unit users in c#

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have my code done that reads all users from a organizational unit, now I need to be able to read the list all those users and display the last login of each user.

Here is the code that reads correctly all the users I need

```
private void btn_LastLoginUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GroupUsers();
}

public void GroupUsers()
{
    PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mydomain", "OU=myEmployees,DC=myCompany,DC=com");

    UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
    qbeUser.Enabled = true;

    // create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
    PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

    // find all matches
    foreach (var found in srch.FindAll())
    {
        lst_Users.Items.Add(found);                        
    }
}
```

I need help reading that data and now display the last login date for each user and populate it to my listbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FunCoder,
This should allow you to get the Last Login Date and Time from the DC. It will convert the user found to an authenticated principle which contains a number of different properties that might help with other information you might be looking for in the future.

```
foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
{
    var auth = found as AuthenticablePrincipal;
    if(auth != null)
    {
       var Name = auth.Name;
       var LastLogin = auth.LastLogon;
    }
}
```

Comment: That completely worked :) thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @FunCoder Glad it helped!